# Processing a list to output in a particular format

Tags: google-sheets, lambda, google-sheets-formula, flatten, google-query-language

I am processing a list to output its items in chunks separated by blank rows as follows. But the result is not working when there are similar items, as shown with the arrows.

[image]

The formula I'm using is `=query(filter(flatten({if(COUNTIFS($A$1:$A,$A$1:$A,ROW($A$1:$A),"<="&ROW($A$1:$A))=1," ",),A1:A}),flatten({if(COUNTIFS($A$1:$A,$A$1:$A,ROW($A$1:$A),"<="&ROW($A$1:$A))=1," ",),A1:A})<>""),"offset 1",0)`

I need some help with it, to get the repeated chunks right too, so that the desired result is following. I've tried tweaking the `COUNTIF` conditions but am struggling.

#### Desired result

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try:

```
=INDEX(LAMBDA(a, QUERY(FLATTEN(SPLIT(QUERY(IFERROR(
 IF(a={""; a},"×"&a,"×​×"&a)),,9^9), "×")), "offset 1", ))
 (A1:INDEX(A:A, MAX(ROW(A:A)*(A:A<>"")))))
```

[image]

Comment: Brilliant! `LAMBDA` is the way to go again! (And I need to learn it more to use it more !). Thank you! :)

Answer (score 1):

When I opened it, there was no answer but here it goes all the same for you or another user

It checks each row with the next one and adds a "|" when they differ, then joins all rows with that same symbol and split by that same symbol, resulting in empty rows between different values

```
=transpose (split(join("|",byrow(A1:A,lambda(each,if(each="","",SI(each=offset(each,1,0),each,each&"|"))))),"|",1,0))
```

Comment: Thank you! While I've accepted the first answer, it's always good to learn with multiple ways of approaching it. Appreciate it!

Comment: Agree with you, I think it's useful to learn different logics and being able to replicate the most suitable to a new scenario in the future. Greetings!

Answer (score 1):

Here's another solution:

```
=index(lambda(a,b,query(flatten(split(
a&if(a=b,,"❆ "),"❆")),"where Col1<>''"))
(filter(A:A,A:A<>""),{filter(A2:A,A2:A<>"");0}))
```